# Weird error: Error:(20, 55) java: void cannot be dereferenced with selenium

Tags: java, selenium

When I try to run the following code I always get the error:

> Error:(20, 55) java: void cannot be dereferenced

I read some of the existing articles but they don't seem to make sense... i.e. I tried adding a return value to the search method, but that didn't change anything...

```
package com.Selenium_intelliJ;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Main {

    public static void search(WebDriver obj, String search){
        obj.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(search).submit();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/josef/Java/geckodriver/geckodriver");
        WebDriver obj = new FirefoxDriver();
        obj.get("https://www.google.com/xhtml");
        search(obj, "test");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendKeys()` doesn't return anything, you can't call `submit()` on it. Split the command to three parts

```
public static void search(WebDriver obj, String search){
    WebElement element = obj.findElement(By.name("q"));
    element.sendKeys(search);
    element.submit();
}
```